# How to use aggregate & names & factor functions properly?

Tags: r

I would like to obtain the mean & sd. However I have difficulties to include labels and factors to the aggregate command.

Sample date:

```
    ID C1 C2 C3     
     1  3  1  0         
     2  2  1  0    
     3  4  1  0     
     4  4  0  1        
     5  5  0  1      

aggregate (C1 , by = list( C2, C3 ), mean)
```

The output is:

```
    Group.1 Group.2   x
       1       0      3.0
       1       1      4.5
```

How can I obtain a function which labels the values and produces such output:

```
       My_Location    Your_location     mean
       my_in           your_out          3.0
       my_in           your_in           4.5
```

Comment: you want them magically to appear?

Comment: :) if that is ok with the science community, than yes

Comment: Do not use `attach`. It's much better to reference your variables within the data.frame as in @akrun's answer.

Comment: The second row of the output should be 0  1  4.5 rather than 1  1  4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dat` is the dataset

```
 res <- with(dat,aggregate(C1, by=list(Time=C2, Area=C3),mean))
 colnames(res)[3] <- "mean"
 res[,1:2] <- c("yes", "no")[(!res[,1:2])+1]
 res
 #  Time Area mean  
 #1  yes   no 3.0
 #2   no  yes 4.5
```

#### data

```
 dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, C1 = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L), C2 = c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), C3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", 
 "C1", "C2", "C3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
 ))
```

#### Update

If you don't want to change the colnames

```
  aggregate(C1~C2+C3, data=dat, FUN=mean)
  #  C2 C3  C1
 #1  1  0 3.0
 #2  0  1 4.5
```

One option is use to `setNames` and change the colnames

```
 setNames(aggregate(C1~C2+C3, data=dat, FUN=mean), c("Time", "Area", "mean"))
 #   Time Area mean
 #1    1    0  3.0
 #2    0    1  4.5
```

#### Update2

Using the same dataset, but your output in Group.1 is not correct.  To get that

```
 dat$C2 <- 1
 res <- with(dat, aggregate(C1, by=list(My_Location=C2, Your_location=C3), mean))
 colnames(res)[3] <- "mean"
 res[,1:2] <- c("in", "out")[(!res[,1:2])+1]

   res[,1:2] <- Map(function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep="_"), tolower(gsub("\\_.*","",colnames(res)[1:2])), res[,1:2])
  res
  #   My_Location Your_location mean
 #1        my_in      your_out  3.0
 #2        my_in       your_in  4.5
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. I just have one question. How can I just keep C2 or C3 or change them to a different column names Time or Area. When I use your approach, and as with my initial example, I always obtain Group1 and Group2 as column names as rnso has shown bellow too.

Comment: @Mamba.  In the solution I provided, C2 and C3 column names are changed to `Time` and `Area`.  I will update with the data used.

Comment: Just the last question on that topic. If I would like to label the colums my_location and your_location and the corresponding dummies as my_in=1 and my_out=0 and your_in=1 and your_out=0 Can I use the structure above?

Comment: @Mamba. Sorry, I didn't quite understand the problem.  Could you update your post and if possible show what you expected.

Comment: I was not sure where to update. I just restated the variables in the above example. Thanx again for your clear presentation.

Answer (score 0):

data.table can also be used:

```
time = sample(c("no","yes"),50,replace=T)
area = sample(c("no","yes"),50,replace=T)
num = sample(1:10, 50, replace=T)

ddt = data.table(time, area, num)

head(ddt)
   time area num
1:  yes  yes   9
2:   no  yes   2
3:  yes  yes   3
4:   no  yes   2
5:  yes   no  10
6:  yes  yes   4

ddt[,mean(num),by= list(time, area)]
   time area       V1
1:  yes  yes 4.636364
2:   no  yes 5.363636
3:  yes   no 5.555556
4:   no   no 7.000000
```

EDIT: a simple function to change format of aggregate output:

```
output = with(ddf, aggregate (C1 , by = list( C2, C3 ), mean))
output
  Group.1 Group.2   x
1       1       0 3.0
2       0       1 4.5

myfn = function(out){
    names(out)=c("Time","area","mean")
    output[out[]==0]= "no"
    output[out[]==1]= "yes"
    out
}

myfn(output)

Time area mean
1    1    0  3.0
2    0    1  4.5
```

Or use aggregate as follows. It shows original column names:

```
aggregate(C1~C2+C3, ddf, mean)
  C2 C3  C1
1  1  0 3.0
2  0  1 4.5
```

Comment: thank your for your suggestion. however, that appoach creates new variables rather than relabel the output or the inital variables temporarily

Comment: thank your for your suggestion. however, that appoach creates new variables rather than relabel the output or the inital variables temporarily. my data sample above is just for the illustration of the problem. so its not about how to create the ideal data output from the scretch rathen than how to manipulate the existing one to obtain the ideal output. I`m sorry for making this confusion.

Comment: Please see my edit above. You will have to specify the terms that are not there in the dataframe (time, area, yes, no).